# Thymeleaf + Boot + AngularJS directives parser error

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

this should be an easy one but I can't find any solution for it.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.0.2 with Thymeleaf on Jetty to support my AngularJS application. But parser throws an exception when attribute directives are used.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Thymeleaf config

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf is working ok but it has a problem with attribute directives like this Bootstrap UI example:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="true">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
        Button dropdown<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I receive this error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "dropdown" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

Where can I tweak Thymeleaf to accept those kind of attributes?

**EDIT**

I've added nekoHTML parser for LEGACYHTML5 but still no result.

Comment: I'm not really a bootstrap expert, but isn't "dropdown" a CSS class?

Comment: No, that is an AngularJS directive which creates specified dropdown.

Comment: I'm not an angular user either, but I wonder why it requires you to write malformed xml. Maybe `dropdown="true"` would work?

Comment: try `data-dropdown` instead of `dropdown`. It should be valid `HTML5` and `dropdown` isn't but a `data-*` attribute is. The latter should be supported by AngularJS.

Comment: @Deinum, not working cuz this is not a standard  AngularJS attribute directive but Boostrap UI directive. Dave Syer that is the syntax od AngularJS, you can make your own custom html tags which angular replaces with another html after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() { ... }
```

with

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver defaultTemplateResolver() { ... }
```

(notice default).

In your case, spring (boot) is not using your configuration for Thymeleaf thus you're getting this "strange" error about parsing non-standard attribute (since default parser is XHTML).

Answer (score 11):

An even easier way to enable to `LEGACYHTML5` in Spring Boot (at least for version 1.1.3.RELEASE that I checked) is to simply add the property

`spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5`

in one of the places Spring Boot looks for properties

(the first that comes to mind is `application.properties`).

Spring Boot's `ThymeleafAutoConfiguration` will take care of the rest

Answer (score 9):

In Spring Boot,

to use legacy HTML5 mode for Thymeleaf,

adding the following property in your 'application.properties':

> spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5

and adding the following dependency

in your 'build.gradle' (if you're using Gradle):

> compile("net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.21")

will be sufficient.

You can find a working example as follows:

https://github.com/izeye/samples-spring-boot-branches/tree/thymeleaf

and a related post as follows:

http://izeye.blogspot.kr/2015/02/orgxmlsaxsaxparseexception-attribute.html

Answer (score 1):

Without changing anything just make it XML compatible:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown="dropdown" is-open="true">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Button dropdown <span       class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Regards